# Usort an array on modified date in php when date is identical

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to sort my array of images by last modified date using the following line.

```
usort($temp_files, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
```

My page is setup to display one image then 4 additional images next to it. But a lot of the images have the same last modified date on the server and I do not have much control over those since the end client uploads them himself. Is there anyway to get around that when the date is identical?

Edit 7/23

So now i have the following, but it still will not sort by date, any ideas?

```
function cmp_by_filemtime_and_basename($a, $b) {
    $cmp = filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);
    if ($cmp == 0) {
        $cmp = strcmp(basename($a), basename($b));
    }
    return $cmp;
}

usort($temp_files, 'cmp_by_filemtime_and_basename');
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? And what do you mean by "getting around that"?

Comment: ORDER BY date_modified, RAND()   will randomise the entries when date_modified is the same, so when you usort they are already in a random order

Comment: I guess that was badly worded, but I mean is there a way to increment those identical dates by a few minutes or something so that i do not lose any of them in the sort. Waygood, how will RAND() affect the modified date when using the usort method?

Comment: @Src1988: Please see the [`touch`](http://php.net/touch) function for changing the filemtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend your comparison function to compare the `basename`s when the `filemtime` is equal:

```
function cmp_by_filemtime_and_basename($a, $b) {
    $cmp = filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);
    if (0 == $cmp) {
        $cmp = strcmp(basename($a), basename($b));
    }
    return $cmp;
}
```

Comment: I implemented this but it doesnt seem to affect the sorting. My page is http://brandybrowauto.com/npo.html. If you click on one of the manufacturers (Toyota is what im using) the sort still doesnt take place. I can post additional code if needed.

Comment: With this line, $cmp = strcmp(basename($a), basename($b));, the images do not sort. If i remove the if statement, it works, but leaves out the ones that have the same lmd.